# Can't connect to Windows 7 "hostednetwork"

Tags: wi-fi

I have been trying and failing to connect my phone (Samsung GT-I8150, running CM10.2) to my Lenovo T420 laptop via Windows 7's "hostednetwork" facility.

The hostednetwork's SSID is visible in my phone, but after I fill in the password, it goes "Connecting" for several seconds, then back to "Saved". No error, no nothing.

I know hostednetwork works because I borrowed a colleague's phone, and his phone has no problem Connecting-Authenticating-Obtaining_IP.

Interestingly, I have no problems connecting my phone to a wifi router in a cafe, or in my home.

What could possibly be the problem between my phone and Windows 7's hostednetwork service?

.

***Edit***: To make things clear:

- `hostednetwork` is Windows 7 facility to turn a laptop's wifi into an Access Point (Infrastructure mode)
- My colleague's phone is an Alcatel D662 (running stock Android GB)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: is "hostednetwork" using infrastructure mode, or ad-hoc? What is "a colleague's phone" (I never heard of that brand ;) Hint: Android does not support ad-hoc natively.

Comment: Thanks, pepoluan! That rules out a) ad-hoc as possible source, and b) makes clear that Android as-such is not the issue here. One more thing you could check: What channel is that hostednetwork using? Depending on regulations, some channels are "out-of-band" by definition in certain regions, so your w7 might use a channel your Android device thinks is "illegal". If ch > 11, this becomes very likely, so make sure to use a channel <= 11.

Comment: Well, by default, activating `hostednetwork` on Windows 7 will give it Channel 11. Perhaps `wpa_supplicant` on CM10.2 is buggy? (I'm grasping at straws here... can't bear seeing my friend using my hotspot happily while I can't even connect)

Comment: Have you tried a different channel (one between 1 and 9)? If that doesn't solve the issue, we can at least rule out this as the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after tearing my hair out and feeling my hair became lighter, I gave up. But then, the wifi of the laptop became even flakier: It can no longer connect to the Office WiFi.

So, I did some drastic measures:

1. Uninstall all ThinkPad utilities that manage the wifi
2. Uninstall the wifi drivers
3. Reboot
4. Reinstall *just* the wifi drivers

Afterwards, I can connect to the office wifi... and `hostednetwork` works! Go figure :-/

Answer (score 0):

On my W540 running Windows 8.1, disabling the "Lenovo Settings Mobile Hotspot Service" fixes the issue.